# Insert into 2 tables with cursor, then use returned scope_identity to insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql, cursor

Basically I want to use an existing table, lets call it `T1`. I have to take that table, row by row and insert different columns into 2 separate tables. For example, `C1`, `C2` into `T2` and `C3`,`C4` into `T3`.

During both of these inserts I need to make sure that the values that I am inserting do not already exist. Unfortunately there are multiple duplicates. Its not my data and it is very dirty. I have to do a ton of casting as is.
Chances are good but not 100% that the column that I want to insert into `T2` or `T3` may exist while the other does not.

Once those inserts are done I need a `@SCOPE_Identity` or another way to uniquely identify and hold in two declared values the auto incremented ID's that `T2` and `T3` create.

These need to then be inserted into `T4` which is a lookup table that mostly only stores FK, its own ID, a comment and a BIT.

I know it is a bit of a task, but I really need some help here.
I have tinkered with multiple cursors and loops, but haven't got there yet.
If I figure something out Ill post a solution, if nobody figures it out before me.

**EDIT:**
So I worked it out. I have posted my code that has been made easy to read and use as an answer. If anyone wants to look at it, comment, make edits etc it will be there. There may be a better way to do it, so please comment if you can.

Comment: show us your best trail for executing your requirements for beginning from what is your actually stuck.

Comment: According to what you hv explain,cursor is not require.only thing missing is your real table structure  and datatype .Then only script can be written.

Comment: I have actually worked it all out. I know if i post it as an answer I won't get votes or whatever. Don't care too much about them. I was just wondering which is the best place to put it.

Comment: It is a bit of a task.... I would suggest to do it with two `MERGE` queries, (one for each table) as it can handle duplicates and also have `OUTPUT` that indicates if it's a new value or an update.  Let me know if you can handle it from here otherwise I'll try to find some time later for some code

Comment: @UV Sorry for late reply to you, but I actually figured it a few days before you posted. My comment is just above yours. Also if you check the answers, I made a generic version and posted it as an answer. I didn't up vote or select it as the answer however. I probably do that, but I wanted to know if anyone could do it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the user safe (I'll just call it that) version of what I eventually used to do my insert. This is really designed for importing data sets that in my eyes would be somewhat difficult to do otherwise without row level inserts. When I ran this it took roughly 2 minutes to insert 50, 000 rows. Bearing in mind that I had way more than 4 column, some columns were large, i had to cast everything at least once (some more than others), and I had to do various cutting using LEFT or RIGHT among other things to clean data for the new tables.

```
Declare @Col1 varchar(50);
DECLARE @Col2 varchar (50);
DECLARE @col3 varchar  (50);
DECLARE @col4 varchar  (50);
DECLARE @T2ID int;
DECLARE @T3ID int;


DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR -- Create the cursor
LOCAL FAST_FORWARD 
-- set the type of cursor. Note you could also use READ_ONLY and FORWARD_ONLY. 
-- You would have to performance test to see if you benifit from one or the other

FOR
--select FROM base table Table1
    SELECT
           Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
           FROM 
           Table1
           WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col3 IS NOT NULL  
           -- If the main columns are null then they are skipped. This was 
           -- required for my data but not necessarily yours.
           OPEN Cur1
           FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO   
           @Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4;
           -- Assigns values to variables declared at the top


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

                -- Select from table 2  
        SELECT @T2ID =  T2ID   
        -- where some data in the table is = to the stored data we are searching for
                FROM Table2
                WHERE @Col1 = [Col1]

                IF @@rowcount = 0
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO T2
                            (Col1
                            ,Col2)
                        VALUES 
                            (@Col1
                            ,@Col2)

                        SET @T2ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                    END;



    -- Selects from Table3      
        SELECT @Col3 =  Table3Col1  
                FROM Table3
                    IF @@rowcount = 0       
                    -- If no rows are returned then proceed with insert
                        BEGIN 
                            INSERT INTO Table3 
                                (col3
                                ,col4)
                            VALUES          
            -- Uses values assigned to the variables from the cursor select
                                (@col3
                                ,@col4)

                            SET @T3ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                        END;


            -- Inserts the gathered row id's into the lookup table  
            INSERT INTO Table4
            (Table2ID
            ,Table3ID)
            VALUES (
            @Table2ID
           ,@Table3ID)

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @Col1, @Col2, @col3, @col4; 


    END;

CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;
```

If anyone has improvements to offer please do. I am open to suggestions.
Also, unless someone wants me to I won't be accepting my answer as correct, as there may be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your table structure and data amount, but I would take an other way to solve this.

1. create a buffer table that holds the data that needs to be inserted in table `T1` and `T2`
2. use this buffer table to populate all of the tables `T1`, `T2`, `T3`

I would try to do this, because using cursors in most cases is slow - you need to try to manipulate the data in batches (group of rows).

How to do this?

1. First, you can find the maximum identity ID in `T1` and `T2`
2. Then, create a table that is going to have the following columns:

   - T1_ID
   - T2_ID
   - C1
   - C2
   - C3
   - C4
   - ShouldBeInsertedInT1
   - ShouldBeInsertedInT2
3. Now, you have to populate the table using the data from `T1` and generating the `T1_ID` and `T2_ID` fields. This is simple `ROW_NUMBER` function `+` the maximum identity ID for table `T1` and `T2`.
4. After the data is in the buffer table, you have to perform two separate updates in order to rise the `ShouldBeInsertedInT` flags. You have to check which of the columns in the buffer table should be inserted in the `T1` and `T2` tables. This can be done with joins, exists, etc - it basically depends on your data and business logic.
5. If you are here, you just need to perform the inserts. For example:

   ```
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.T1 ON

   INSERT INTO T1
   SELECT T1_ID, C1, C2
   FROM bufffer
   WHERE ShouldBeInsertedInT1 = 1;

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.T1 OFF

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.T2 ON

   INSERT INTO T2
   SELECT T2_ID, C3, C4
   FROM bufffer
   WHERE ShouldBeInsertedInT2 = 1;

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.T2 OFF

   INSERT INTO T3
   SELECT T1_ID, T2_ID
   FROM bufffer;
   ```

This is just a concept, so you must change this code. Note, that the whole process may need to be in a transaction in order to be sure the maximum  identity IDs for `T1` and `T2` are not changed.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea. Ill give it a try. Just a few things
1. `T1` is the source table
2. T2` is the first main table which has a few hundred duplicates
3. `T3` is the secondary table which has thousands of duplicates
4. `T4` being the dictionary lookup table)
If it was as simple as all the information was unique this may work, but then again so would 3 separate sorted inserts.